# Docker container logging

Tags: docker, logging

There is something I don't understand with Docker logs.

Reading the documentation I see that, by default, Docker uses the JSON File logging driver.

> By default, Docker captures the standard output (and standard error) of all your containers, and writes them in files using the JSON format

So, if I'm doing

```
docker run -it --name log1 alpine:latest
```

followed by (so inside the container) a simple `ps -ef`, I can see the result of the command in the logs using `docker logs log1`

Now I'm keeping the container running.  If, in another session, I'm doing

```
docker exec -it log1 ps -ef
```

nothing more arrives in the logs.

Even with

```
docker exec -it log1 sh
```

`ps -ef` (inside the container) produces nothing in the logs.

Back to the 1st session, all commands output is logged again.

What am I misunderstanding ?

Comment: docker logs -f log1 = -f, --follow         Follow log output

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to find explicit explanation for that on docker's site, but to me it looks like following.

First, when you start your container (`docker run`), dockder allocates main process (`PID 1`) for that and container is considered alive while this process doesn't exit. This process has its own `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, which are btw connected to your console (`-it` flag).

These are the handlers, which are being collected and logged by docker daemon.

When you run `docker exec`, it creates new process in the container, and this new process does not inherit io handlers (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) from `PID 1`. So, all new sessions, created by `docker exec` seem to have their own, separate streams, not being logged by daemon.